# Remove duplicate from txt file that contains different sentences but consist of the same words on PHP

Tags: php, duplicates, txt

I want to remove duplicates from txt file. Now, I use this to remove duplicates:

```
$lines = file('input.txt');
$lines = array_unique($lines);
file_put_contents('output.txt', implode($lines));
```

The problem is that code only remove duplicate for a case like `beef bbq recipe` and `beef bbq recipe` only.  In my case, if the txt file contains keywords like :

```
beef bbq recipe
beef easy recipe
beef steak recipe
bbq recipe beef
beef bbq recipe
recipe bbq beef
```

Will return with this result :

```
beef bbq recipe
beef easy recipe
beef steak recipe
bbq recipe beef
recipe bbq beef
```

Instead, I want the result looks like this :

```
beef bbq recipe
beef easy recipe
beef steak recipe
```

So, I want cases like `beef bbq recipe`, `bbq recipe beef` and `recipe bbq beef` to be considered as duplicates too. Is there a solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode) and [`sort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to bring the keywords into the same order for all your lines before removing duplicates:

```
$lines = file('input.txt');

// sort keywords in each line
$lines = array_map(function($line) {
    $keywords = explode(" ", trim($line));
    sort($keywords);
    return implode(" ", $keywords);
}, $lines);

$lines = array_unique($lines);
file_put_contents('output.txt', implode("\n", $lines));
```

This will iterate your array and order the keywords for each line alphabetically. Afterwards, you can remove the duplicated lines using [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: Hi, I've been try your code but back with this result https://prnt.sc/YIGiXvNrhOqZ 

It seems to have a problem with spacing, how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You mean everything is on the same line? The `implode` in your sample snippet is missing the first parameter for `"\n"` (newline), I think this might be  the reason.

Comment: Okay, this depends on your input data. Is it possible that you have multiple consecutive spaces in it?

Comment: Additionally, you have to remove the attached newline character from each line. I updated my answer to use [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim) accordingly.